# How to get dynamic random paramterization values in nUnit Tests referring to same data source?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Refer code below, As of now we get same parameters in SampleTest1, SampleTest2 & SampleTest3.

I am looking
for dynamic values in each of the test i.e.SampleTest1, SampleTest2 & SampleTest3.

```
internal static Dictionary < string, string > randomValue = SelectRandomValue();
internal static object[] RandomValue = {
    new object[] {
        randomValue["ValueType"], randomValue["ValueName"]
    }
};
internal static Dictionary < string, string > SelectRandomValue() {
        int elementAt = new Random().Next(10);
        string ValueType = GetValues().ElementAt(elementAt).Key;
        List < string > ValueNames = GetValues().ElementAt(elementAt).Value;
        return new Dictionary < string, string > () {
            {
                "ValueType",
                ValueType
            }, {
                "ValueName",
                ValueNames[new Random().Next(ValueNames.Count)]
            }
        };
    }
    [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(RandomValue))]
public void SampleTest1(string ValueType, string ValueName) {
    // Test Code
}

[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(RandomValue))]
public void SampleTest2(string ValueType, string ValueName) {
    // Test Code
}

[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(RandomValue))]
public void SampleTest3(string ValueType, string ValueName) {
    // Test Code
}
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that Unit Tests with *random inputs* may *randomly fail* as well, potentially making it harder to track.

Comment: true but we are choosing the random from a finite list of values (say. 10 elements).

Comment: Some would argue that if you have a finite test cases then you should test all of them everytime. But I understand there is never one hard rule to life, and people usually have good reasons to do things a certain way. As long as the input that contributed to a failing case is recorded properly, I do agree that random testing can be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's set aside the complications of the random value generation for a moment, because it's actually not an important part of the problem.

You have three tests that use the same `TestCaseSource`. That source is a st atic array, which is initialized once and once only by it's static constructor. Since the static constructor is only called once, the array can only be initialized once and can only contain one set of values. All the tests using the same static field or simple property will always get the same values.

I haven't tried this, but I believe a workaround for you may be to change `RandomValue` to a **method** returning the same object array. This will work unless / until NUnit is modified to cache the return value. I happen to know it used to do that in NUnit V2, but it was removed in 3.0. I don't believe it has been put pack... so far!

If that fails, you'll simply have to use a different `TestCaseSource` for each of your tests.

The rest of this answer addresses the expected follow-up question "Why does it work that way?"

NUnit is designed so that using the most obvious approach gives you what most people want most of the time. For most people, having all the tests using the same `TestCaseSource` receive the same data is exactly what is needed. It would be surprising and possibly breaking for the data to be different in each case.

In your question, you used the word "dynamic." Although the word may have various meanings, NUnit's data generation has never been what I would call dynamic. Personally, I would expect dynamic generation to mean that the data is re-created each time the test is run. But that's not how NUnit works. The data is created **once** at the time the test is loaded.

In fact, implementing some sort of dynamic generation - defined as I just did - is actually the subject of a number of NUnit issues for many years... search for "dynamic" on the nunit github site. But for now, it requires a fair bit of user code to implement it yourself.

PS: I'm assuming you **actually** need the test methods to each have separate data. That's something you'll have to think about yourself.